# Cross domain uploading

Tags: file-upload, cross-domain

Are there ways to upload files using a form in url A that points to url B in its "action" attribute without redirecting the page to url B?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Can you be more explicit about what you mean by "redirecting"?

Comment: Normally, when you submit a form, it would redirect to the url defined in "action". I was asking if there is way for this not to happen. I am aware that it can be done via Javascript/Ajax, Iframes, etc but there are some cross domain issues with those solutions. I just want to hear what you guys think.

Comment: So you want a solution that doesn't involve a script? Just plain HTML? Then no. You need AJAX to post back a form without posting back the whole page.

Comment: I am open to those solutions. My only restriction is no flash/swfupload.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 3 years later, but since I had this same question myself today, I figured I'd post my solution here. It's not the prettiest, but it uses an iframe, which should help it be more supported by legacy browsers. The biggest challenge of the iframe is that you can't read the contents of an iframe if it's on another domain for security reasons (the browser restricts said functionality).

In essence, my solution is this:

1. The user selects a file to upload.
2. The form that encases the file field sends a POST request targeting a hidden iframe.
3. A PHP script executes in the handler script, uploading the file.
4. When the script is done (or errored out), it sends a `Location` redirect, sending the iframe back to `HTTP_REFERER`, which will be the on the same domain as the form page, which means that the script will be able to read the contents.
5. In order to send useful information along the redirect, I simply add onto the GET parameters of the referrer page. These can be extracted and read via JavaScript.

**The HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="http://other/website/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
<br /><br />
<img id="avatar" />
```

**The JavaScript:**

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $('<iframe></iframe>').attr({name: 'iframe', id: 'iframe'}).prependTo($('body')).load(function () {
        var response = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(/[\\?&]_response=([^&#]*)/.exec(this.contentWindow.location.href)[1]).replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        if (response.error) {
            alert(response.error);
        } else {
            $('#avatar').attr('src', response.url);
        }

        $(this).remove();
    });
    $(this).attr('target', 'iframe');
});

$('input[name="avatar"]').change(function () {
    $('form').submit();
});
```

**The PHP:**

```
<?php
define('MAX_SIZE', 28 * 1024); // 28 KB
define('UPLOAD_PATH', 'uploads/');
define('UPLOAD_URI', 'http://other/website/uploads/');

header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

function format_size ($bytes) {
    for ($labels = array ('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'), $x = 0; $bytes >= 1024 && $x < count($labels)-1; $bytes /= 1024, ++$x);
    return round($bytes, 2) . ' ' . $labels[$x];
}

function respond ($message) {
    parse_str(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);
    $params = array_merge($params, array ('_response' => json_encode($message)));
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?' . http_build_query($params));
    exit;
}

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    switch ($file['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            respond(array ('error' => 'You may not upload a file larger than ' . format_size(MAX_SIZE) . '.'));
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            respond(array ('error' => 'The server could not upload the file.'));
            break;
    }

    if ($file['size'] > MAX_SIZE) {
        respond(array ('error' => 'You may not upload a file larger than ' . format_size(MAX_SIZE) . '.'));
    } else if (!in_array($file['type'], array ('image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg'))) {
        respond(array ('error' => 'The uploaded file must be a PNG, GIF, or JPEG image.'));
    }

    $split = explode('.', basename($file['name']));
    $ext = array_pop($split);
    $name = implode('.', array_merge($split, array (uniqid(), $ext)));
    if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_PATH . $name)) {
        respond(array ('error' => 'The server could not upload the file.'));
    } else {
        respond(array ('url' => UPLOAD_URI . $name));
    }
}
?>
```